# Value of property is undefined in reactJS render() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple react class that upon rendering returns a title and an image based on the image path it receives in props from its parent component.

Every time i try to access property this.props.eImage (local image path) the value of said property is undefined, as in eImage: undefined for the first two renders(component is for reasons unknown rendered 4 times). I have access to the property but for some reason not to its value.

This causes the render method to throw an error "Cannot find module 'undefined'.

I tried using lifecycle methods such as getDerivedState and component willRecieveProps to first store the image path in state and then use it in render but to no avail, both have the same result.

This is very frustrating, because it is a simple task but I can't get it to work. Please help. The shortened code is:

Parent :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Title from './Title/Title.js';
import Description from './Description/Description.js';
import OrderSection from './OrderSection/OrderSection.js';
import './excursionStyle.css';

const excursionList = [
  {
    excTitle : "Музейный Дрезден",
    excDescription: `Дрезденская картинная галерея, как всегда, радует :)`} 
  ]

class Excursion extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
        };
      };

    getCurrentIndex = (name) => {
      return excursionList.find(exc =>
        exc.excTitle === name
      )
    }

  componentDidMount() {   
      const currentExcursion = this.getCurrentIndex(this.props.match.params.name);
      this.setState(currentExcursion);
    };
    
    render(){    
      return (
          <div className="body">
            <div className="excursion">
            <Title eTitle={this.state.excTitle} eImage={this.state.excImageUrl}/>
                <Description eDescription = {this.state.excDescription}/>
                <OrderSection eTitle = {this.state.excTitle}/>
          </div>
          </div>
            );
    }
        
}
```

Child :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Title.css';

class Title extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);     
    }
    render() {  
        console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <div>
            <header className = "flex">
                <p className = "f2 b">{this.props.eTitle}</p>
            </header>
            <div>
                    <img src={require(this.props.eImage)}></img>                                                                      
            </div>
            </div>    
        );
    }
}

export default Title;
```

Comment: Are those images relative to your folder? What props are you passing BTW?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Excursion` component starts with this state:

```
this.state = {
};
```

That means when it renders `Title`, using `this.state.excImageUrl` is accessing a property that doesn't exist on the state object, resulting in the value `undefined`. So your `Title` component sees `eImage` with the value `undefined`.

If `Title` needs that property, you need to not render `Title` until you have it. That's usually done with a guard of some kind, e.g. (in `Excursion`):

```
render(){    
  const eImage = this.state.excImageUrl;
  return (
      <div className="body">
        <div className="excursion">
        {eImage && <Title eTitle={this.state.excTitle} eImage={eImage}/>
            <Description eDescription = {this.state.excDescription}/>
            <OrderSection eTitle = {this.state.excTitle}/>
        }
      </div>
      </div>
        );
}
```

Note the `{eImage && <Title ... />}` structure, which is the guard. React ignores expression placeholders whose expression value id `undefined` or `null` or `false`, so if `eImage` is `undefined`, `{eImage && <Title ... />}` will be `undefined` (`Title` won't be used). But if `eImage` is a non-blank string (for instance), the `{eImage && <Title ... />}` results in a `Title`.

---

Side note regarding:

> ...component is for reasons unknown rendered 4 times...

The way `Excursion` is written, it will always get rendered at *least* twice: Once without anything on `state`, and then again after `componentDidMount`'s state update. It will also get rendered everytime its props change, so if (for instance) its parent component is giving it one `match` value to start with but then updating it with another one, it'll likely render three times. If the parent componen tupdates `match` more than once...

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by setting Excrusion state before it renders for the first time(using componentWillMount). Thanks a lot for answers.